# Parsing text within brackets from one column in a dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a subject column in my dataframe that I would like to move bracketed text from and into another requestor column (while removing the brackets in the process). Not all of the subject column row entries have bracketed text.

Basically what I'm looking to do is shown in the before and after below.

**Before:**

```
Subject

0 Data Request [John Smith]

1 Project [Sarah Johnson]

2 Emails

3 Lunch

4 Working Session [Jake Williams]
```

**After:**

```
Subject            Requestor

0 Data Request     John Smith

1 Project          Sarah Johnson

2 Emails           None

3 Lunch            None

4 Working Session  Jake Williams
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at [`pd.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html).

Comment: can a row have multiple brackets or values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
df['Requestor'] = df['Subject'].str.extract(r'\[(.*)\]').astype(object).replace(np.nan, 'None')
```

To trim the first column try like @Manakin:

```
df['Subject'] = df['Subject'].str.replace('\[.*\]','').str.strip()
```

Comment: you can use the same logic to clean the `Subject` column `df['Subject'] = df['Subject'].str.replace('\[.*\]','').str.strip()`

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!!! Give me a moment to accept this answer.